# Is the harmonic mean directly proportional to the sum of the numbers?

Tags: means

Which of the following sentences is mathematically correct:

1. The **harmonic mean** of a set of numbers is **directly proportional** to the sum of numbers.
2. The **arithmetic mean** of a set of numbers is **directly proportional** to the sum of the numbers.

In my opinion, the first sentence is incorrect because, for example, if the sum of the numbers increases twice the harmonic mean does not increase twice. Whereas the second sentence is true.

Am I right?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to give an explicit counterexample for one case and a proof for the other.

Comment: 1. Harmonic mean of (10,10) = 10; harmonic mean of (10,30) = 15 and not 20.               2. Arithmetic mean of (x,y) = (x+y)/2; Arithmetic mean of (2x, 2y) = (2x+2y)/2= x+y

Comment: 1. is good. For 2., just note that ${x_1+\cdots+x_n \over n} = {1 \over n} \sum_{k=1}^n x_k$. The constant of proportionality is ${1 \over n}$.

Answer (score 0):

A y B are directly proportional if A/B is some constant.

Since your hipothesis, the aritmetic mean $\frac{n_1+n_2+\cdots+n_k}{k}$  isdirectly proportional to $n_1+n_2+\cdots+n_k$, because cocient is constant ($1/k$).

Comment: Luis, I think You mean the constant is 1/k !?

Comment: @Ami you are right!, I improved the answer